# How do I push to GitHub https repos using my ssh key?

Tags: ssh, git, github

I can push to `git@github.com:wting/repo.git` links without a password prompt since it's using my ssh-agent. However when I push to `https://github.com/wting/repo.git` it always asks for username and password.

The issue can somewhat be alleviated by using [password caching](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git), but I'd rather not use that.

This mainly pops up when using gists because they only show an https link (e.g. `https://gist.github.com/123.git`). I don't want to modify the URL of every gist I clone to use the `git@gist.github.com:123.git` version.

How do I set it up so that git uses my ssh-agent when pushing to an https address?

Relevant URL:
[Why does GitHub recommend HTTPS over SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041729/why-does-github-recommend-https-over-ssh)

Answer (score 3):

1. put your public key to [github.com](http://github.com)
2. use `ssh -T git@github.com` to identify if public key works
3. under your repo ,`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<user>/<project>.git`
4. `git push`

Answer (score 1):

I've resorted to writing a git wrapper function:

```
function gc {
    if [[ ${1} =~ "github.com" ]] && [[ ${1} =~ "https" ]]; then
        git clone ${${1/https:\/\//git@}/\//:} ${@:2}
    else
        git clone ${@}
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[<s>Set it in your GitHub account.</s>](https://github.com/settings/ssh)

According to your own link it seems unsupported, I guess you could write a small function in .bashrc to rewrite the remotes in git style.

Comment: I already have the SSH keys added to my account. I'm asking how to get it working with https links and not just git@github.com links.

Comment: Why not just use the Git link? Gists might not support R+W access...

Comment: Gists do support r+w access, but only the https link is shown. I would rather not have to modify the clone link every time I clone a gist.

Comment: @WilliamTing: Oh right, just checked and works here. I believe this to be a local problem and thus not related to GitHub, please double check your configuration and follow the relevant steps again... Is there a firewall in the way?

Comment: You can push to https using ssh-agent? There's no firewall in the way.

Comment: I'm testing with this simple [gist](https://gist.github.com/4573850). There is only the "master" branch. `git remote -v` results: `origin  https://gist.github.com/4573850.git` Using `git push origin` still brings up password prompt.

Comment: Interesting, I was trying this on a gist that was already present therefore I removed my previous comment. It seems they have changed from git to https, it indeed doesn't work on https for me but I have no idea why. Does it list somewhere that https is supported through ssh-agent?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but I'm hoping someone knows the answer. :)

Comment: According to your own link it seems unsupported, I guess you could write a small function in .bashrc to rewrite the remotes in git style.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually doing that right now. T_T